# How would I connect to a WinDSX server with .Net so I can query the database?

Tags: c#, sql, data-science-experience

I need to be able to query a WinDSX server from .Net. This is the first time I have worked with a DSX server and I can't seem to find anything that really explains how to do this. Is there some type of ODBC driver I can use?

Comment: An IBM product? good luck finding any doco or assistance. Going by this https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/ibm-data-science-experience-dsx-platform/, the DSX server is spark compute. It quite possibly doesn't actually have any data in it. Data may be seperate. I tried downloading the PDF link in that page and it took me to a dead end. This is what you'll find over and over with IBM products. It's a dinosaur.

Comment: This https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Watson_Studio says that DSX is now "Watson Studio" - it's an old product meaning it's going to be even more difficult to find doco. So do you have an instance of this right now that you need to use?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Parse documentation is an understatement. LOL I have a client that is using WinDSX that I need to be able to send queries to.